# TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

Tags: javascript

I have this inside the method in javascript and the line where it went wrong in the error.

The error in console is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of null".

```
   if (date == kDate) {
     if (k.result.info.length > 0) {
       ref.pr.m.push({
         name: i.name + ":" + i.tag,
         inf: k.result.info.length,
         date: ref.getMonthString(new Date(a).getMonth()) + " " + new Date(a).getDate()
       });
      }
    }
```

For the answer:

I just need to add some conditions in the `if` like this `if (k.result && k.result.info && k.result.info.length > 0) { ... }` so that it could avoid error like TypeError when encountered `null`

Comment: Probably `va.sR` contains `null`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `va.sR` is equal to `null` in at least one of your iterations.

In order to avoid these kinds of errors, you can add something like this to your `if` condition:

`(va.sR && va.sR.iF && va.sR.iF.length > 0){//do stuff}`

This means that the script won't throw an error even if the values are `undefined` or `null`. Of course, this isn't necessarily a good thing if you expect them to always be objects.

Answer (score 0):

`va.sR` might be equal to `null` or `undefined` in any one of your iteration. To avoid these errors you can add a check to your conditional statements like this.

```
if (va.sR && va.sR.iF && va.sR.iF.length > 0) {
     ref.pr.mD.push({
       image: i.name + ":" + i.tag,
       inf: va.sR.iF.length,
       date: ref.getMonthString(new Date(a).getMonth()) + 
       " " + new Date(a).getDate()
     });
}
```